# How to report each test-failed test step in Jenkins using surefire-reports

Tags: maven, soap, jenkins, soapui, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Maven project setup for running my API automation tests. I configured this Maven job to run on Jenkins and the test reports are generated using Surefire reports. I would like to see all the failed test steps in a list format inside a failed test. For now I can see all the failure tests but the steps are not listed.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>${basedir}/abc-services-bkt.xml</projectFile>
                        <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <printReport>true</printReport>
                        <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Can some one give me clue?

Comment: I believe that there should be property assertions in the test steps, so that you would be able to identify test failures. I believe that you achieve nothing even if you know what step failed as you need to run the entire test case, not just the failed step.